# How to create transparent tabbar in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In my iOS app I'm using `UItabbar`.I want to set transparent colour to `tabbar`. How can i create a transparent `tabbar`?

Comment: subclass and add background color as UIClearColor

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a fully transparent TabBar in UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413352/how-to-get-a-fully-transparent-tabbar-in-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITabBar fully transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539203/uitabbar-fully-transparent)

Answer (score 1):

Set the TabBar's tint color to clearColor.
code1:

```
 [[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

code2:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

You can use any1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UIVIEW and set its opacity/alpha value or just clear the background color. Then you need to insert the view in UITabBar

See the link for the example

[How to get a fully transparent TabBar in UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413352/how-to-get-a-fully-transparent-tabbar-in-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: If you find similar question then you should mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]; 
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```